# ReactNative: undefined is not an object (this.state.listAccounts)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
class Widgets extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            accessToken: "",
            listAccounts:[],
        }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({listAccounts: this.loadAccountsData()})
    }
    loadAccountsData(){
         //return data from server
    }
    render() {
        return (
                <Content>
                    {this.state.listAccounts.map( (Account) => <Account accountData={Account} />)}
                </Content>
        )
    }
}
```

above is blue print of my code. I am unabele to access state in render?
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.listAccounts.map')

Answer (score 1):

you are setting state on an async request. you need to wait till the response comes back to set your state.

```
class Widgets extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            accessToken: "",
            listAccounts:[],
        }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.loadAccountsData();
    }
    loadAccountsData(){
         somerequest().then( (response) => {
             this.setState({listAccounts: response});
             // or whatever the data is that your accounts are
         });
    }
    render() {
        return (
                <Content>
                    {this.state.listAccounts.map( (Account) => <Account accountData={Account} />)}
                </Content>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue was happening because I think Hot Reloading didn't build with the new state after I added. Manually reloading the iOS simulator fixed the issue for me.